# How can I aggregate string data in DataStage?

Tags: datastage

I have the following data coming into DataStage:

| customernumber | hometelephone | mobiletelephone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | NULL | 07123456 |
| 1234 | 0120202 | NULL |

What I want out the other end is:

| customernumber | hometelephone | mobiletelephone |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | 0120202 | 07123456 |

Simple I thought, just use an Aggregator - and indeed this does work to some degree. However, it converts the strings to floats, then back to strings again, resulting in my phone numbers becoming 7.1235e+06 (or similar).

Is there some other way to take the maximum value of a string?

What I essentially want would be easy in SQL:

`SELECT customernumber, MAX(hometelephone), MAX(mobiletelephone) FROM <input> GROUP BY customernumber;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two options for this problem:

- Aggregator stage: Use the property "Default to decimal output" to get a decimal output. Details can be found [here](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=tab-aggregator-stage-aggregations-category). There is nothing wrong in converting data types.
- Transformer: Aggregation cans also be done in a Transfomer stage by using [LastRowInGroup](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/iis/11.7?topic=stage-key-break-detection) to detect the group change.